# Displaying images while still having a console for a java based text game

Tags: java, jframe, text-based

I want to make a java text game, but also want picture representations of what's happening. How can i make it so that i have a console and an area for the current image above? Jframe?

Comment: Yes, you can use JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some psuedocode that is the basic structure of what I think you want.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Game");
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
frame.setContent(panel);
JTextArea consoleArea = new JTextArea();
panel.add(new MyGameCanvas(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
panel.add(consoleArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, but it returns the message Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method setContent(JPanel) is undefined for the type JFrame
 MyGameCanvas cannot be resolved to a type

 at Game.testmain.main(testmain.java:15)